# It is possible to run a iPhone emulator with docker?

Tags: docker, containers

Is it possible to run an IOS app in a docker container?

I would like to have a container in HTTP server , to manage and test the application

Comment: I think not. You can't run GUI applications in a docker container.

Comment: You can run virtualbox in a docker, inside the virtualbox you can run OSX and xCode

Comment: @AAber Thank you , i try your solution ; but i found only high sierra

Comment: I have Mojave running in VirtualBox